# Does the word 'unastute' exist?

Tags: antonyms

I was searching for an antonym to 'astute' and an antonym derived from the word itself seemed perfect in the context. Does such a word exist?

Comment: No, it appears it is not used. You might take a poetic licence and use it, *un-astute.*

Comment: @Josh61 -- Not used?  Do you have evidence to that effect?

Comment: I would have expected the negated form to be [***inastute***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22inastute%22) - but that gets only 150 hits in Google Books, compared to 281 for [***unastute***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unastute%22) (neither word appears in the full OED, or any free online dictionaries, so far as I can see).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, I expected inastute to be more popular.  There are places where one or the other "sounds better".

Comment: Inastute is a term I remember from childhood, and my mother, the English teacher.  I can only reference her, as an authority, since the word seems to be less common than most.  It means "not astute" or unable to use advanced concepts through a lack of education, or intelligence.  It's kind of a substitute for stupid, with a lesser amount of vilification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Un-" is a perfectly legitimate prefix, and there's nothing to stop you from prepending it to "astute".  Though not frequently, [it *is* used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unastute%2Cinastute&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunastute%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinastute%3B%2Cc0), and mostly, it appears, in fairly literate works, vs magazines and popular fiction.  "Inastute" is also used, though less so.

Comment: @Charon - I said it was not frequently used.  Habilatory is even less frequently used, but is still a legitimate word.

Comment: Yes, fair enough, I take your point.

Comment: Isn't **unastute** sort of *unsmart*?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we dumb down the antonym in this case so that the subject understands what we mean about them? (kidding)

Frankly, I think "[OBTUSE](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obtuse)" is the antonym I prefer.

```
OBTUSE
adjective
1. not quick or alert in perception, feeling, or intellect; not sensitive or observant; dull.
```

Comment: Find this the best alternative. Thanks for this word (reminding of it, as I am a non-native English speaker)

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard or read *unastute*, or *inastute*.

But how about ***myopic***?

> lacking foresight or intellectual insight.

<sub>OED</sub>

The phrase *astute observation* conveys a meaning of keen insight, for which *myopic* would serve as a good antonym.

Comment: Myopic is not an antonym of astute.

Comment: @HotLicks - But astute is synonymous with perspicacious, and that particular definition could be considered to be an antonym of myopic, no?

Comment: to our antonym is *imperspicacious*...

Answer (score 0):

If ***astute*** is '*of keen penetration or discernment, esp. in regard to one's own interests; shrewd, subtle, sagacious; wily, cunning, crafty'* (OED), then perhaps ***dull-witted*** is a better antonym ('*having a dull wit; stupid*' (OED).

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***dense*** and ***thickheaded***

> dense:  slow to understand :  stupid, thickheaded *was too dense to get the joke*
>
> thickheaded: sluggish and obtuse of mind

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dense)